# ClassCastException when declare fragment in xml code

Tags: android, fragment, android-support-library

I declared a Fragment in a layout then try to inflate that view but I always get the ClassCastException. Please help me to solve this.

This is my layout source:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/fillparent"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.app.Fragment
        android:name="com.ihnel.tinyapp.xskt.view.ResultView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

    <ihnel.lib.topbar.TopBar
        android:id="@+id/container_topbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/topbar_header" >
    </ihnel.lib.topbar.TopBar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the java code where the exception is thrown:

```
container = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.container, null);
```

And this is the logcat:

```
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ihnel.tinyapp.xskt/com.ihnel.tinyapp.xskt.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Class is not a View android.support.v4.app.Fragment
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1996)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1174)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4503)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Class is not a View android.support.v4.app.Fragment
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:599)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:741)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:491)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:262)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1846)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at com.ihnel.tinyapp.xskt.Home.onCreate(Home.java:28)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4504)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1960)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    ... 11 more
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be cast to android.view.View
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:1380)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:554)
11-17 13:17:34.689: E/AndroidRuntime(21674):    ... 22 more
11-17 13:17:34.690: E/IBINDER_HOOK(21674): open whitelist file error
```

This is the ResultView fragment:

```
   package com.ihnel.tinyapp.xskt.view;

import ihnel.tinyapp.xskt.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;

This is the ResultView fragment:

    public class ResultView extends Fragment {

        /** The webview which is used to show result. */
        WebView webview_main;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.resultview, null);
            init(view);
            return view;
        }

        /**
         * Inits the fragment view.
         *
         * @param view the root view.
         */
        private void init(View view){
                }
    }
```

Comment: android:name="com.ihnel.tinyapp.xskt.view.ResultView" what is mean this line ?

Comment: What class does ResultView extend?

Comment: Can you also show us your com.ihnel.tinyapp.xskt.view.ResultView. Make sure that you are importing the right packages and do not use 'this' for context if you have used it anywhere in your class, use the full qualified name like 'className.this'.

Comment: com.ihnel.tinyapp.xskt.view.ResultView is the name of my Fragment. ResultView extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment. android:name attribute must be set to the Custom Fragment.

Comment: Please see my update. and Please do not down vote when you can't answer my question!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `com.ihnel.tinyapp.xskt.view.ResultView` isn't a fragment! [Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding)

Comment: Hi dmon, do you have any idea?

Comment: That's not how you add a fragment via XML. Read the link I posted previously more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your layout xml like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
**xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"**
style="@style/fillparent"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

I've had same problem. I could not solve this problem by any suggested solutions. When I edited my layout xml like that, the problem was gone magically. Still I don't know why the problem never occurs again even if I remove the line, xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools".